# non-admin domain user has un-given administrator privileges

Tags: windows-7, administrator, windows-domain

I have a very weird behavior. a non-admin domain user can perform admin actions. the following tests are what i tried to get my head around the issue but cant seem to understand what is happening.

- `whoami /all` shows that the user is a member of
  `BUILTIN/Administrators`
- `net localgroup administrators` doesn't have the user
- the user is not a member of any group that is a member of `BUILTIN/Administrators`
- when the user initiates a task that needs privilege, the UAC popup is opening ( so it is not an issue of UAC ) as far as i can dig up
- admin actions that I have performed using this user (successfully) are :

1- change local administrator password
2-delete a printer
3-install a software

not sure what more test can be done to handle the issue.

Comment: “shows that the user is a member of BUILTIN/Administrators” - I don’t understand, is this a typo, what admin functions are we talking about exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound hi, no it isnt a typo. It means that this command returns that the user is in the Administrators group

Comment: Why is a non-Administrator part of that group?

Answer (score 0):

Your user has BUILTIN\Administrators access. You need to remove it:

1. Press ⊞ + R, type "compmgmt.msc" without the quotes, and hit Enter.
2. Drop down "Local Users and Groups" and then go to Groups.
3. Right-click "Administrators" and hit "Add to Group..."

- 

1. Select your Domain user i.e. DOMAINNAME\useraccountname123
2. Hit Remove
3. Apply if available
4. Hit OK.

***If the user is not showing in compmgmt groups as you stated, try the following more advanced technique:***

Open an elevated (admin) command prompt and type `net localgroup Administrators` and see if the user is showing there. If so, try the following next:

`net localgroup Administrators DOMAINNAME\useraccount123 /delete`

then `net localgroup Administrators` again to confirm.

[image]